# What is the PRIMARY index in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have just learnt how to create indexes in mysql and executed such a query in mysql workbench connecting to a mysql 8.0 instance:

```sql
use test;
create table idx (
id int not null unique,
name char(5),
primary key(id),
key(name)
);
show index from idx;
```

The result grid is:

```
# Table, Non_unique, Key_name, Seq_in_index, Column_name, Collation, Cardinality, Sub_part, Packed, Null, Index_type, Comment, Index_comment, Visible, Expression
'idx', '0', 'PRIMARY', '1', 'id', 'A', '0', NULL, NULL, '', 'BTREE', '', '', 'YES', NULL
'idx', '0', 'id', '1', 'id', 'A', '0', NULL, NULL, '', 'BTREE', '', '', 'YES', NULL
'idx', '1', 'name', '1', 'name', 'A', '0', NULL, NULL, 'YES', 'BTREE', '', '', 'YES', NULL
```

It makes me confused that there are two indexes of key_name=PRIMARAY and key_name="id" because `id` is the primary key. What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `id` index comes from the `unique` option for the `id` column. The `PRIMARY` index comes from `primary key (id)`.

Since a primary key is always unique, you don't need the `unique` option, and then it won't create the extra index.

Answer (score 0):

Indexing can be done with multiple column of table, In B+ Tree has a root key with lots of child node. It means when you search something in your index, classification is done with primary key first.
Let say you have 1 million data and your index's primary key is name order is ASC alphabetical. If you are looking for age=15 and name=John and primary key of index is name. What db engine will do is:
Check for 'John' start index. Then find age=15 in all 'John'.

If name more identifier then you should use name as primary key.

Check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_indexing)